# json undefined var

Tags: javascript, google-maps

So I am trying to use the Google Maps feature with the following codes and the json data.
But I get **Error: location is undefined** error. I dont really understand why because I defined in my codes.
I am new to JavaScript, any suggestion to make this code appreciated.

```
    var data = <%=JSON.stringify(Info, null, 2) & vbNewline%>;

  function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(48.404840395764175, 2.6845264434814453);

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var markers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      var location = data[i];
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.latitude,
          location.longitude);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


{ "firstname": "", "lastname": "", "location": { "latitude": "48.4048403957642", "longitude": "2.68452644348145" } } { "firstname": "", "lastname": "", "location": { "latitude": "48.4050236871384", "longitude": "2.68512690051361" } } { "firstname": "", "lastname": "", "location": { "latitude": "48.4048403957642", "longitude": "2.68452644348145" } } { "firstname": "", "lastname": "", "location": { "latitude": "48.7570941168018", "longitude": "2.16670989990234" } } { "firstname": "", "lastname": "", "location": { "latitude": "48.404922961092", "longitude": "2.70020564018949" } } { "firstname": "", "lastname": "", "location": { "latitude": "48.8739279353421", "longitude": "2.32875823974609" } } { "firstname": "", "lastname": "", "location": { "latitude": "48.4048403957642", "longitude": "2.68452644348145" } } { "firstname": "", "lastname": "", "location": { "latitude": "41.0349860434783", "longitude": "28.9774059609177" } }
```

Comment: Are there 100 (or more) elements in your `data` array? If not, `location` will be undefined when `i` is greater than `data.length`.

Comment: No there is actually one for now since I am testing it.

Comment: Well there's your problem. [techfoobar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10783130/790695) shows you how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably do

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
```

instead of

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
```